# What is the CA configuration file syntax? (ca-config.json)

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, certificate-authority, cfssl

I can't seem to find the configuration reference for creating a CA with `cfssl`.

I'm going through [k8s the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) and trying to understand every single step. In [this step](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md#certificate-authority), he makes a `ca-config.json` for use with `cfssl gencert -initca ca-csr.json`. I'd like to see the reference for this, but I can't find it. Where is it?